# Copying fast current pulse

Tags: current

I am wondering if there is a way to copy fast current pulses generated by a circuitry A to circuitry B.
Circuit A is very sensitive to loading. It does not like anything above 100Ohms.
I was thinking of something like a current mirror, but the one with low input impedance doesn't fit well.

Comment: So you need a buffer? To preserve current rather than voltage? (which is more typical). Provide more details.

Comment: How fast are we talking?

Comment: To copy current pulses with few tens of microamp peaks and pulse width of 5 nano seconds. Thank you.